# Is it possible to set horizontal gradient to text via CSS? (left letter one colour, right - another colour)

Tags: css, reactjs, text, gradient

Is it possible to set horizontal gradient to text via CSS? (left letter one colour, right - another colour).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , yellow);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, yellow);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

### Example using React and styled-components:

```js
const ColorText = styled.h1 `
  font-size: 72px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red , yellow); 
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
`;

const App = () => (
  <ColorText>Colorful Text</ColorText>
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(<App/>);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot)
Is it cross browser compatible?

Comment: Depends if you support IE8 or earlier , http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: to increase browser compatibility, you may use mix-blend-mode , example http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWMxdL, else for a full compatibility, actually an image is the only way ....

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` support: https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode