# Multi-Colored Text in one line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a title with multiple colors and I've already found a way but I'm not quite satisfied with it. I want it to be on attribute or a h1 element, with the text and the multiple colors

Here's what I've been using

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1D;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}

#super {
  color: #FF6447;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

#bone {
  color: #FFB951;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

#craft {
  color: #FFF547;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a id="super">SUPER</a><a id="bone">BONE</a><a id="craft">CRAFT</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is

Comment: Maybe it could be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884260/is-it-possible-to-set-horizontal-gradient-to-text-via-css-left-letter-one-colo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654928/how-can-i-give-different-color-for-each-letter-in-a-text-field Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're after, but if you want the font color to be based on an attribute you can use `data`. The nice thing about this approach instead of using ids, is that you can easily set/get the values or elements with Javascript if needed.

Also, you should be using `span` tags rather than `a`.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1A1A1D;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
}

span[data-color] {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

span[data-color="super"] {
  color: #FF6447;
}

span[data-color="bone"] {
  color: #FFB951;
}

span[data-color="craft"] {
  color: #FFF547;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span data-color="super">SUPER</span><span data-color="bone">BONE</span><span data-color="craft">CRAFT</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```css
#someID {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

.super {
  color: #FF6447;
}

.bone {
  color: #FFB951;
}

.craft {
  color: #FFF547;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a id="someID"><span class="super">SUPER</span><span class="bone">BONE</span><span class="craft">CRAFT</span></a>
</div>
```

In this case you have only one `a` tag.