# How do I put a text on a text

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

Is there a way to put text on a text like above in CSS or JS?

Comment: use 2 different elements and set position with css. try writing your code first

Comment: Do  you mean to put text on image ?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 3):

Use a parent of `relative position` and add text as `absolute` child elements:

```css
.elements {
  position: relative;
}

.outer-element, .inner-element {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.outer-element {
  color: blue;
}
.inner-element {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 35px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div class="outer-element">GTA</div>
  <div class="inner-element">ROLEPLAY</div>
</div>
```

[**Code fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8dy9765b/)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884260/is-it-possible-to-set-horizontal-gradient-to-text-via-css-left-letter-one-colo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div style="position:absolute; top:0;left:0;">some text</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:5;left:5;">some text</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:10;left:10;">some text</div>
<br/>
<div style="position:absolute; top:110;left:100;">some text</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:105;left:105;">some text</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:100;left:110;">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add text in front of an image using CSS.

Check : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```css
.container {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .firstline {
      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      left: 15px;
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
    }

    .secondtline {
      position: absolute;
      top: 22px;
      left: 40px;
      font-size: 70px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: orange;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%;">
      <div class="firstline">GTA</div>
      <div class="secondtline">ROLEPLAY</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: check again, one mistake was present

Comment: it's just settings in CSS (you can try changing size of texte, reducing margin etc...), check again... ROLEPLAY is now on GTA.